# Yo and iLo? Are they the same?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras

Hace poco encontré el siguiente texto en un video:

> Tienes un marido perfecto!
>
> iLo sé!

Esta fue la primera vez que vi la expresión **iLo sé**.

Hice algunas investigaciones y encontré algunos otros ejemplos de uso de esta expresión:

> Said no nos ha traicionado, algo ha pasado, **ilo sé**!
>
> **iLo sé**! José, iSon ellos! ya llegaron.

Curiosamente, en una frase que encontré se usa tanto "yo sé" como "ilo sé":

> **yo sé**, **ilo sé** muy bien!, que mi redentor vive.

Estoy en duda. ¿"Yo" e "ilo" tienen el mismo significado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que estás viendo no es la letra "i", sino un [signo de apertura de exclamación](https://www.rae.es/dpd/interrogaci%C3%B3n) ("¡"). Las oraciones exclamativas en español deben comenzar con un signo de apertura de exclamación ("¡") y terminar con un signo de cierre de exclamación ("!"). Por ejemplo,

- ¡Ordena tu cuarto!
- ¡Estoy cansado de oír siempre la misma excusa!
- No te rindas, ¡inténtalo!
- No me lo tienes que explicar, ¡lo sé perfectamente!

En el tercer ejemplo, puedes ver la diferencia entre el signo de apertura de exclamación ("¡") y la letra "i". En el cuarto ejemplo, el signo de exclamación está delante de la palabra "lo", lo que puede llevar a confundirlo con una nueva palabra "ilo". Pero esto es solo una confusión: la palabra "ilo" [no existe](https://dle.rae.es/ilo).